# Material that acts as a "sponge" for sulfuric acid?

Tags: acid-base, materials, reference-request

I would like help with a materials problem I am looking into that pertains to a product I would like to develop.

What I seek is some kind of substrate that acts like blotter paper does. Ideally, the substrate will be a thin material which can be soaked in sulfuric acid and hold a small amount "suspended" in it without a reaction taking place.

I have looked into which plastics are best compatible with sulfuric acid (HDPE and PTFE) but was unable to find any information about "sponge-like" forms of these plastics.

Comment: I think glass wool would work.